# How do I kill all other running python processes without killing the parent process

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to stop all python processes without killing the current running script. Here is the code I wrote so far.

```
import psutil
import os

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    pinfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'name'])
    procname = str(pinfo['name'])
    procpid = str(pinfo['pid'])
    if "python" in procname:
        print("Stopped Python Process ", proc)
        proc.kill()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `if`'s condition, from the current

```
if "python" in procname:
```

to

```
if "python" in procname and procpid != str(os.getpid()):
```

Comment: @ChuckBoyd, it's good practice to **accept** the answer, not just express thanks for it:-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to get which pid your program have. And check if all one of the element you iterate through do not have the same pid.

```
import psutil
import os


this_proc = os.getpid()

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    procd = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'name'])
    if "python" in str(procd['name']) and procd['pid'] != this_proc:
        proc.kill()
```